# Looping grunt-watch with new version of autoprefixer

Tags: gruntjs, autoprefixer

Up until recently I've been using a similar gruntfile to this with success. However in my latest project grunt watch is looping continually - sometimes 4 times, sometimes 15 times or so before stopping - I can't figure out how to change the gruntfile to get it working properly again.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        // Define our source and build folders
        js_path: 'public_html/js',
        img_path: 'public_html/img',
        css_path: 'public_html/css',
        imagemin: {
            dynamic: {
                files: [{
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= img_path %>/',
                        src: ['*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                        dest: '<%= img_path %>/'
                    }]
            }
        },
        concat: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    '<%= js_path %>/jquery-ui.js',
                    '<%= js_path %>/plugin_royal_slider.js',
                    '<%= js_path %>/plugins.js',
                    '<%= js_path %>/plugin_selectboxit.js',
                    '<%= js_path %>/plugin_picturefill.js',
                    '<%= js_path %>/plugin_jquery_placeholder.js',
                    '<%= js_path %>/plugin_pickadate.js',
                    '<%= js_path %>/script.js'
                ],
                dest: '<%= js_path %>/output.js',
                nonull: true
            }

        },
        jshint: {
            beforeconcat: [
                '<%= js_path %>/jquery-ui.js',
                '<%= js_path %>/plugin_royal_slider.js',
                '<%= js_path %>/plugins.js',
                '<%= js_path %>/plugin_selectboxit.js',
                '<%= js_path %>/plugin_picturefill.js',
                '<%= js_path %>/plugin_jquery_placeholder.js',
                '<%= js_path %>/plugin_pickadate.js',
                '<%= js_path %>/script.js'],
            afterconcat: ['<%= js_path %>/output.js'
            ],
            options: {
                sub: true,
                "-W004": true,
                "-W041": true,
                "-W093": true,
                "-W032": true,
                "-W099": true,
                "-W033": true,
                "-W030": true,
                ignores: ['<%= js_path %>/jquery-ui.js']
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy H:M:s") %> */\n',
                mangle: true,
                compress: {drop_console: true} // true supresses console.log output: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#turn-off-console-warnings
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= js_path %>/js.min.js': ['<%= js_path %>/output.js'] 
                }
            }
        },
        postcss: {
            options: {
                map: true,
                processors: [
                    require('autoprefixer')({browsers: 'last 2 versions'}),
                    require('csswring')
                ]
            },
            dist: {
                src: '<%= css_path %>/*.css'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            options: {nospawn: true},
            scripts: {
                files: ['<%= js_path %>/*.js'],
                tasks: ['build']
            },
            css: {
                files: ['<%= css_path %>/*.css'],
                tasks: ['build']
            },
            grunt: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify', 'postcss']); // run manually with grunt build or run grunt watch - ctrl c to exit
    grunt.registerTask('optimg', ['imagemin']); // run with grunt optimg
    grunt.event.on('watch', function (action, filepath) {
        grunt.log.writeln(filepath + ' has ' + action);
    });
};
```

Current dependencies:

```
"grunt": "~0.4.5",
"grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.1",
"grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.9.4",
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.2",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.1",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
"grunt-postcss": "~0.6.0",
"csswring": "~4.0.0",
"autoprefixer-core": "~6.0.1",
"autoprefixer": "~6.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is that `concat` generates its file into your `js_path` directory, and watch monitors all js files in that directory. So what happens is:

1. you modify a js source file
2. watch detects your modification and launches concat
3. concat generates output.js
4. watch detects output.js and launches concat
5. 3 then 4 repeat - until you're saved by watch buffering (which prevents triggering too quickly in sequence)

To solve it, you have to remove the concat output from the watchlist.
What I recommend is to have concat output to a build directory outside your sources - it's best practice to separate build artefacts from source elements anyway. Define a `build_path` config variable and use it in your concat target.
If you really can't do that for a good reason, manually remove output.js from the watch with a negative directive (http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns):

```
watch: {
  scripts: {
    files: ['<%= js_path %>/*.js', '!<%= js_path %>/output.js'],
    tasks: ['build']
  },
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. The problem only started after an update to autoprefixer, so it seems to be directly related to that. However I tried your suggestion (remove output.js from the watch task), but it didn't help. I've had success in moving postcss to a separate build task.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the postcss to a separate task has solved the problem for me.

Here are the changes to the gruntfile:

```
watch: {
    options: {nospawn: true},
    scripts: {
        files: ['<%= js_path %>/*.js'],
        tasks: ['build_js']
    },
    css: {
        files: ['<%= css_path %>/*.css'],
        tasks: ['build:css']
    },
    grunt: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
    }
```

and

```
grunt.registerTask('build_js', ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify']);
grunt.registerTask('build_css', ['postcss:dist']);
```